# Django imagekit and dynamic paths

Tags: django, dynamic, path, imagekit, django-imagekit

I'm using imagekit provided at: [imagekit](https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit)

So, I've defined two class model:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    #photo_wrapper = models.ForeignKey(PhotoWrapper, blank=True, null=True)
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos')
    thumbnail = ImageSpec([Adjust(contrast=1.2, sharpness=1.1),
            resize.Crop(50, 50)], image_field='original_image',
            format='JPEG', quality=90)
    num_views = models.PositiveIntegerField(editable=False, default=0)

    class IKOptions:
        # This inner class is where we define the ImageKit options for the model
        spec_module = 'myspecs.specs'
        cache_dir = 'static/photos'
        image_field = 'original_image'
        save_count_as = 'num_views'

class Country(models.Model):       
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)        
    country_photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s' % self.country_name
```

The problem is that each photo is created in the "static/photos" path.
My intent is to save the image and the thumbnail with a dynamic path, based on the country name..

For example, for the country "Argentina", the dynamic path will be "static/photos/Argentina/"

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing two different versions of ImageKit. The newer versions (1.0+) no longer use the inner `IKOptions` class, so all of that is being ignored. (The save_count_as functionality was also removed.)

If you want to control the cache filename, the `ImageSpec` constructor accepts a `cache_to` kwarg which—like `ImageField`'s `upload_to`—can be a callable. Here's the current documentation for `cache_to`:

```
Specifies the filename to use when saving the image
cache file. This is modeled after ImageField's ``upload_to`` and
can be either a string (that specifies a directory) or a
callable (that returns a filepath). Callable values should
accept the following arguments:

    - instance -- The model instance this spec belongs to
    - path -- The path of the original image
    - specname -- the property name that the spec is bound to on
        the model instance
    - extension -- A recommended extension. If the format of the
        spec is set explicitly, this suggestion will be
        based on that format. if not, the extension of the
        original file will be passed. You do not have to use
        this extension, it's only a recommendation.
```

So you'll just have to create a function that accepts those arguments and returns the path you want, and use that in your model like so:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    thumbnail = ImageSpec(..., cache_to=my_cache_to_function)
```